# Why Zend_Debug::dump() doesn`t working

Tags: zend-framework

I was trying to use this function like this:

```
$test = 'tekst';
Zend_Debug::dump($test);
```

It does not print anything ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this part of code is not actually running? (is this part of larger website?)

Maybe you didn't have Zend loaded, and your PHP shows error (like 'Can't find class Zend_Debug') but you have `error_reporting` disabled?